# fastest way to make vim use new plugin in ~/.vim/bundles

Tags: vim, macvim, pathogen

I'm using pathogen with vim.

When I add a new plugin to the ~/.vim/bundle directory what's the fastest way to make my existing MacVim window start using it? Do I have to close it and open a new one or is there a quick command I can run?

Comment: I would like an answer that wasn't "use something different."

Answer (score 2):

You can use [vim-addon-manager](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2905) instead of pathogen. It uses bundle-like directory too, but when you call

```
ActivateAddons snipMate
```

if snipmate was not installed, VAM will install it and then source so that you don’t need to restart. You will have to add some call to `vam#ActivateAddons()` with `'snipMate'` in arguments to the vimrc though.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind trying an alternative to Pathogen, check out [Unbundle](https://github.com/sunaku/vim-unbundle#readme) which lets you call `:Unbundle` manually to "rescan" your `~/.vim/bundle` directory without closing Vim.  It also supports filetype specific bundles, which can be manually rescanned in a similar fashion.